# How do I capture the output of a Python 2.7 script without needing to go to Linux?

Tags: python-2.7, logging, stdout

How might I capture the output of my script w/out having to go to Linux (script.py > new_file.txt) ?

Comment: How about explain what platform you're on

Answer (score 1):

Set stdout to the file you want to save:

```
import sys
sys.stdout = open('file', 'w')
```

Comment: Thanks! I can only see the output of direct print statements in my new file though. What I need it to do is capture the output to the screen on the fly as the program executes.

Comment: What else is producing output? Find out what those things are outputting to (stderr?) and capture that as well.

Comment: It's reaching to a database and grabbing back items as it does so.

Comment: If I do, script.py > new_file.txt...I can see it all. Yet, that's what I'm hoping to avoid.

Comment: Ah, then I assume your database library is the thing producing the output that isn't captured (not using python's sys handle, naturally). So yeah, there's not much you can do there unless you have access to that library's source and feel like getting your hands dirty. You'd have to switch it on the command line (the thing you want to avoid). Unless you want to cheat and fork a new shell process (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-from-python-and-capturing-the-output for that)

Comment: Something like this?

subprocess.check_output(['ls', '-l'])

It needs to write to a certain file name though. How might I enable that?

Comment: check_output, I believe, returns all of the stdout as a string. You could then write that returned string to the file of your choosing. (I haven't tested this)